# Simple Examples to Use Insert_Rows DB hook in Airflow

Tags: airflow

Can someone help me with simple examples to use Insert_Rows DB hook in Airflow?
I have a requirement to make an insert into a table.
How do I do that and make commit to the database.
Starting with airflow, so simple examples will help understand in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method. For example, if you have database A that you read a row from it and want to insert it to a similar database B.

Here is an example of `INSERT`:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM A WHERE ID > 5")
connecetion_to_B.insert_rows(table="B", rows=cursor)
```

`UPSERT`:

```
 cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM A WHERE Id > 5")
 connecetion_to_B.insert_rows(table="B",
                              rows=cursor,
                              replace=True,
                              replace_index="id",
                              target_fields=['Id','memberId'])
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways. it depends on what is you preferered mode.

Based on you description, I think the most simple is use dboperator + SQL. It need strong Databases admin experience + a piece of airflow experience. For example:

```
process_order_fact = PostgresOperatorWithTemplatedParams(
    task_id='process_order_fact',
    postgres_conn_id='postgres_dwh',
    sql='process_order_fact.sql',
    parameters={"window_start_date": "{{ ds }}", "window_end_date": "{{ tomorrow_ds }}"},
    dag=dag,
    pool='postgres_dwh'
```

Above code was copied from https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/etlexample.html

Good Luck.